# why there is so much confusion surrounding launch screen in xamarin.ios

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, launch-screen, launchimage, uiimageasset

In image asset editor we can add launch image but it'll not appear in devices I can say atleast iPhone devices but If you ignore to add LaunchImage in assets xamarin won't let you compile the app.so you have to add the LaunchImage and at the same time you have to have Launch Screen.storyboard Why is this anomaly ? and how to keep on using static images 
I have created separate imageset in asset library and added a image view in  launch screen and referred that newly added imageset but its not working screen appears empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a Xamarin problem, but iOS itself.

Launch image required for iOS version lower than 8.0. So if you want to support them, you need to add all images in to assets.

LaunchStoryboard you can use for all iOS version above 8.0 (included). It will stretch out automatically for each device.

You can select most appropriate solution for your project in Info.plist
[image]